# NoSuchMethodError when loading Spark Dataframes from Ignite

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

I'm getting an error trying to load a spark Dataframe from and Apache Ignite table. I've found that I get this even with the stock "Person" sample here: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignite-data-frame

I'm just testing in the spark shell which I'm launching with these packages:

```
--packages org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark:2.6.0,org.apache.ignite:ignite-core:2.6.0,org.apache.ignite:ignite-scalar:2.6.0,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.1
```

I'm loading the DF like this:

```
scala>  val personDf = spark.read.format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE).option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE,  "person").option("config", CONFIG).load()
personDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [AGE: int, NAME: string]
```

Any Data frame operations result in failures in package.scala

```
scala> personDf.show()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType;ZLorg/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ExprId;Lscala/Option;)V
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.optimization.package$.toAttributeReference(package.scala:121)
<snip>
```

another example:

```
scala> personDf.count()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType;ZLorg/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ExprId;Lscala/Option;)V
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.optimization.package$.toAttributeReference(package.scala:144)
<snip>
```

I also tried with spark SQL examples:

```
scala> val igniteDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = 'Mary Major'")
igniteDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [AGE: int, NAME: string]

scala> igniteDF.count()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType;ZLorg/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ExprId;Lscala/Option;)V
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.optimization.package$.toAttributeReference(package.scala:144)
```

Am I missing a package somewhere?

Comment: Try downloading the ignite jar and pass it as a --jars instead of --packages.

Comment: yes, try download jar and run `./bin/spark-shell --jars "path/to/ignite-spark.jar,path/to/ignite-core.jar,path/to/ignite-scalar.jar,path/to/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11.jar" ---other_args`

Comment: @mrsrinivas How did you resolve this issue? I am in the same bucket and even though I am passing everything as jars it still showing me the same error when I try to load and do a simple thing like count.

Comment: Do you use spark 2.4? You need org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark-2.4